# Android - alternative to Toast messages

Tags: android

In my application I want to have certain information pop up in/over whatever activity the user happens to currently be running. Toast works great for simple text (it draws over every activity and can be called from anywhere), but I want something more elaborate. The method that creates this information that I need displayed is in the Application base class rather than any particular activity.

The only way I can do this with what I know is have the Application class send a broadcast and then have the activity show a dialog, but this would require modifying all the activities and duplicating a lot of code.

I'm sure there is a smarter way to do this, but I just don't know enough about Android yet.

Comment: You can use a Custom toast.

Comment: Can I call it from the Application class so it displays in whatever activity that's currently running?

Comment: you can display the toast in activity and use application class for the data to be displayed in toast

Answer (score 5):

I have created a library called [Crouton](https://github.com/keyboardsurfer/Crouton) that is a Context sensitive alternative to `Toast`. It can not be invoked from within the Application class, but from the Activity. Might help you nonetheless.

Comment: He wanted the opposite: Context insensitive (ie Activity insensitive) messages

Answer (score 2):

I use [Snackbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar.html),

**1**.In your build.gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
```

**2**. In your class you have to add this import

```
import android.support.design.widget
```

**3**. And in your code

```
Snackbar.make(view, "your message", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show();
```

Also you can check this example in [GitHub](https://github.com/CabezasGonzalezJavier/ProximitySensor)